# How do I highlight the max values across every column in a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting, highlighting

Looking for a way to use conditional formatting to highlight the max value in every column of a pivot table.

Comment: "highlight the max value in every column" - do you mean the biggest value in EACH column or ONE MAX VALUE across the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in pivot tables, but for normal use-

1. Select the range of interest and note the starting cell (e.g.  A1)
2. Alt+O, D or however you like to open the conditional formatting dialog ;)
3. Add condition
4. Choose "Formula"
5. Enter `=A1=MAX(A1:A65536)` as the formula (`MAX(A:A)` may also work but I haven't tried it).  If the starting cell isn't in column A, use the starting column instead
6. Pick your formatting / OK out of the dialogs
7. Enjoy your highlighting :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, you have to build your references in the formula using the indirect function.

Let's assume you have this Pivot Table.
[image]
<sup>**our pivot table**</sup>

If you want to highlight the maximum value of every single column, select the interval B5:f8 and then start the conditional formatting for creating a new Rule.

In the new window select **All cells showing "XXXXXXX" values for "YYYYY" and "ZZZZZZ" ("YYYYY" and "ZZZZZZ" for this example are the Row and Column Labels)**
Then use this formula:

```
=B5=MAX(INDIRECT("r1c"&COLUMN()&":r8c"&COLUMN(),0))
```

This is the result.
[image]
<sup>**Formatted pivot table**</sup>